# Excel table to specific page and paragraph in word VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have the following code to copy data from excel and paste it into word, where I choose the page to put it in. However I am facing difficulties placing it exactly where I want inside that page

```
Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(file, ReadOnly:=False)
wsTableToCopy.UsedRange.Copy
wApp.Selection.GoTo 1, 2, Name:="2" 'What wdGoToPage / Which wdGoToNext , name:="pagenumber"
wApp.Selection.Paste
wDoc.Save
wApp.Quit
```

How can I select for example place it in the second paragraph on that page?

Comment: Hi @Slavi, have you tried using bookmarks? You can insert a bookmark in the word document wherever you like and have somerthing like `.Bookmarks("Bookmark1").Range.Text = "Whatever" `

Comment: Hey, that actually worked except that I used
`.Bookmarks("bookmark").select` and then `selection.paste`